# Android socket client times out

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, client

I hope someone can contribute to a solution for my problem. I've spent a lot of my time searching for a solution, including this forum, but haven't been successful.

I have a php socket server running and I'm trying to have my android application connect to it and exchange data. I know that the php server works, at least for a php client so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere within the android client.

The application is run on android 7" tablet, Android 2.1

Below are, what I think, the most relevant code snippets. I think it's important to mention that this occurs both when there is wi-fi connection and not. I'm sure I don't need all of the permissions shown in the manifest but I included them at the suggestion of one of the threads I read.

The exception that is thrown says: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected". I've tried increasing the timeout limit without luck

This is the android client that tries to connect to an external server:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class test extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = "socketTest";

    public SocketAddress remoteAdr = new InetSocketAddress("111.222.333.444", 1234);
    public Socket socket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d(TAG, "Start the socket thread..");
        startThread();
    }

    void startThread(){
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Log.d(TAG, "Socket thread started !");
                boolean loop = true;

                while(loop){
                    try{
                        Log.d(TAG, "Create the socket");
                        socket = new Socket();

                        Log.d(TAG, "Try to connect the socket");
                        socket.connect(remoteAdr, 15000);

                        Log.d(TAG, "I'm never shown..");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error when connecting: " + e);
                    }

                        Log.d(TAG, "Done trying");
                        loop = false;
                    }
                }
            };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

My manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.henda.test"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.socket.test.test"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The php socket server:

```
$loop = 1;
set_time_limit (1);

// set some variables
$host="111.222.333.444";
$port = 1234;

// Create the socket, bind it to a port and start listening (accepts 3 connectinons in the queue).
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket \n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket \n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener \n");

do{    
    // spawn another socket to handle communication and
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection \n");

    // Accept incoming connections and wait for user input
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input \n");

    switch(trim($input)){
        case "someCase":{
            // do something here, f.x. connect to a database
            // code omitted
            break;
        }
        case "END":
        {
            $loop = 0;
            break;
        }
    }while($loop);
socket_close($socket);
```

I've already tried to see if my InetSocketAddress is valid with

```
InetSocketAddress p1 = (InetSocketAddress)remoteAdr;
Log.d(TAG, "isUnresolved: " + p1.isUnresolved());
```

Using my correct IP-address and port number this returns false.

Then for comparison I tried a different IP address which does not exist. This returned true on the isUnresolved() check. The port.connect() threw an UnknownHostException with the message "Host is unresolved".

From this test I guess my InetSocketAddress is valid.

Does anyone have a clue why my client gets timed out ??

EDIT:
I tried my code (see above) on a HTC Desire and the log showed the same information so it appears as if this problem is not fixed to my tablet. Am I missing something in my code, either on the client side or the server side ?

I wonder if the server is refusing the connection and that's why the client times out. I mean my InetSocketAddress is valid so I must be doing something right.

I include the log generated with "adb logcat t:D AndroidRuntime:E". Does anyone have a clue after reading this log

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D/t       ( 1132): --------------------------------------------
D/t       ( 1132): Start the socket thread..
D/t       ( 1132): Socket thread started !
D/t       ( 1132): Create the socket
D/t       ( 1132): Try to connect the socket
W/InputManagerService(  738): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46fe5eb0 (uid=10001 pid=831)
I/startInputInner(  831):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=2
W/InputManagerService(  738): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46fe5eb0 (uid=10001 pid=831)
I/startInputInner(  831):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=1
W/InputManagerService(  738): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46fe5eb0 (uid=10001 pid=831)
I/startInputInner(  831):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=0
W/InputManagerService(  738): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46fe5eb0 (uid=10001 pid=831)
I/ActivityManager(  738): Displayed activity com.henda.test/com.socket.test.test: 350 ms (total 350 ms)
I/startInputInner( 1132):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=2
I/startInputInner( 1132):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=1
I/startInputInner( 1132):  mService.startInput fail,retry left=0
E/libagl  (  738): copybit failed (Unknown error: -1)
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -54
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 54
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm(  738): GC freed 1990 objects / 104424 bytes in 169ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -55
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm( 1529): GC freed 261 objects / 14536 bytes in 80ms
D/dalvikvm(11058): GC freed 8233 objects / 526624 bytes in 87ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -57
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm(  976): GC freed 215 objects / 17880 bytes in 94ms
D/dalvikvm(11058): GC freed 8566 objects / 519976 bytes in 83ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -53
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -53
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED  1
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm( 1523): GC freed 43 objects / 2064 bytes in 73ms
D/dalvikvm(11058): GC freed 8232 objects / 526504 bytes in 87ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -52
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 54
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -54
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm( 2199): GC freed 499 objects / 24120 bytes in 95ms
D/dalvikvm(11058): GC freed 8566 objects / 519944 bytes in 84ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -55
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm(  831): GC freed 1006 objects / 55656 bytes in 107ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -54
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 48
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/dalvikvm(11058): GC freed 8231 objects / 526584 bytes in 83ms
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER RSSI-APPROX] reply=[WIFI RSSI -53
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): Global Control: cmd=[DRIVER LINKSPEED] reply=[LINKSPEED 36
D/WPA_CTRL_IFACE( 2064): ]
E/t       ( 1132): Error when connecting: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected
D/t       ( 1132): Done trying
```

Comment: To move the obvious out of the way, can you access that ip addy from the browser on the tablet, or ping it from a shell on the tablet?

Comment: Yes, if I type my IP address in the browser on the tablet I get a 200 OK response.

Comment: Should I have used something other than a php socket server ?

Comment: Could the reason be a firewall on the server that is blocking the communication ?

Comment: Doesn't your php client connect to the same address/port?

Comment: I understand that; the point is if the php client connects, then there's no firewall issue? Or you're running the client on the same machine as the server. If yes, do try connecting to the server from a different machine; even with telnet.

Comment: @Torp: Yes,the php client and the php server use the same address/port but the php client is not the problem, the php server and php client are working well together. It is the Android client that is the problem and is unable to connect to the php socket server.

Comment: @Torp: The php scripts are on the same server, only to debug the socket server. I think you are right. My next step is to try the php client from another location.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check your type of network connection, if you are using wifi, the issue may caused by your setting of wifi's channel, change it & try again.

good luck.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the wifi channel has something to do with this? The OP's point about the unknown host exception makes it seem unlikely to have to do with a problem below the TCP/IP layer, such as WiFi channels.